# algorithm for solving resource allocation problems

Tags: algorithm

Hi  I am building a program wherein students are signing up for an exam which is conducted at several cities through out the country. While signing up students provide a list of three cities where they would like to give the exam in order of their preference. So a student may say his first preference for an exam centre is New York followed by Chicago followed by Boston.

Now keeping in mind that as the exam centres have limited capacity they cannot accomodate each students first choice .We would however try and provide as many students either their first or second choice of centres and as far as possible avoid students having to give the third choice centre to a student

Now any ideas of a sorting algorithm that would mke this process more efficent.The simple way to do this would be to first go through the list of first choice of students allot as many as possible then go through the list of second choices and allot. However this may lead to the students who are first in the list getting their first centre and the last students getting their third choice or worse none of their choices. Anything that could make this more efficient

Comment: My gut feel is that a "perfect" algorithm would be NP-complete, and you'll have to settle for an approximation.

Comment: Why not just give priority to the first students who signed up? You have to discrimate them anyways.

Comment: The problem is that we have been specifically told by the client not to go with a first come first serve approach. The reason being that there is that the students in different locations have different dates to fill up their exam form.So its not their fault that they filled up their form later than the others.

Comment: Why not picking the students randomly? No discrimination this way ;)

Comment: The process of allocating resources is not called sorting. I changed the title to more closely match your problem.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a variant of the classic [stable marriages problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) or the [college admission problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Resident_Matching_Program#Matching_Algorithm). The Wikipedia lists a linear-time (in the number of preferences, O(*n*²) in the number of persons) algorithm for the former; the NRMP describes an [efficient algorithm](http://www.nrmp.org/res_match/about_res/algorithms.html) for the latter.

I suspect that if you randomly generate preferences of exam places for students (one [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) per exam place) and then apply the stable marriages algorithm, you'll get a pretty fair and efficient solution.

Answer (score 4):

This problem could be formulated as an instance of [minimum cost flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem). Let N be the number of students. Let each student be a source vertex with capacity 1. Let each exam center be a sink vertex with capacity, well, its capacity. Make an arc from each student to his first, second, and third choices. Set the cost of first choice arcs to 0; the cost of second choice arcs to 1; and the cost of third choice arcs to N + 1.

Find a minimum-cost flow that moves N units of flow. Assuming that your solver returns an integral solution (it should; flow LPs are totally unimodular), each student flows one unit to his assigned center. The costs minimize the number of third-choice assignments, breaking ties by the number of second-choice assignments.

Answer (score 0):

There are a class of algorithms that address this allocating of limited resources called auctions. Basically in this case each student would get a certain amount of money (a number they can spend), then your software would make bids between those students. You might use a formula based on preferences.

An example would be for tutorial times. If you put down your preferences, then you would effectively bid more for those times and less for the times you don't want. So if you don't get your preferences you have more "money" to bid with for other tutorials.